# How to add input search field with roudned corners?

Tags: css, search, html, input

I am tryting to add seach field in my header:

```
      <form class="searchform">
      <span><input type="text" class="search rounded" p 
      laceholder="Search..."></span>    
     </form>

e.searchform{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
height: 50px;
}
.search { 
padding:6px 15px 6px 30px;
margin:3px; 
background: url('./images/search.png') no-repeat 8px 6px; 
 }

.rounded { 
border-radius:55px; 
-moz-border-radius:15px; 
-webkit-border-radius:15px; 
 }

 input[type=text]{
 color:#bcbcbc;
  }  

  .lighter, .light, .dark {
   width:95%;
  height:50px;
  padding:40px 25px;
  }

 .lighter{
 background: url('./images/lighter_grey.jpg');
   }
.lighter input[type=text]{
border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
background-color:#fcfcfc;
}
.light{
background: url('./images/light_grey.jpg');
}
.light input[type=text]{
border:1px solid #acb1b7;
background-color:#fcfcfc;
 }
input[type=button], input[type=button]:hover {
position:relative; 
left:-6px;
border:1px solid #adc5cf;
background: #e4f1f9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%); /* FF3.6+ 
*/
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-
 stop(0%,#e4f1f9), color-stop(100%,#d5e7f3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* 
  Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4f1f9', endColorstr='#d5e7f3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
color:#7da2aa;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

For some reason,the css styling does not affect pretty much the form. FOr example the form does not get the desired width.What could be the problem.

Comment: You set the width in css classes you didn't assign to the input field: .lighter .light .dark

Comment: How can I add this classes to the imput field? for example: if my class is <input class="test">  input.test[type=button] ??

Comment: <input type="text" class="search rounded lighter" p        laceholder="Search..."> for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is technically correct with the exception of your first line of `css`. You need to remove the `e` before the `.searchform` declaration for it to accept those styles.

The code below is working correctly (see demo here: https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/eyJrJG) however if your input still doesn't show rounded borders it might be that your styles are being overwritten by another stylesheet.

You can fix this by either declaring your stylesheet after the conflicting one, adding a more specific declaration or adding `!important` (not recommended).

**HTML**

```
<form class="searchform">
    <span>
        <input type="text" class="search rounded" placeholder="Search...">
    </span>    
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Removed the 'e' from this line */
.searchform {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
}

.rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 55px;
}

/* More specific styles (if the above doesn't work) */
form.searchform {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
}

form.searchform input.rounded {
    border-radius: 15px;
}

/* Demo styles to better view border radius */
.searchform {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.rounded {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

It's also worth noting that prefixed `border-radius` isn't required and the values are different to the base style. If you insist on using them it's worth changing them all to `15px` or `55px`.

**Additional**

If you're wanting to use your `.light`, `.lighter` & `.dark` classes I'd change the following code too:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="search rounded light" placeholder="Search...">
```

**CSS**

```
/* Replaces: .lighter input[type=text] */
input.lighter {
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

/* Replaces: .light input[type=text] */
input.light {
    border: 1px solid #acb1b7;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
```